# C# richtextbox and reading huge file

Tags: c#, file, richtextbox

I am reading a huge file (hundreds of MB) and displaying  it to a richtext box. my program would freeze when I run it. can anybody give me advice? is is because the way I read the file? or is it because there is somekind of limit on richtextbox ? I tried to increase the maxLength properties 2147483647, but it says "property value is not valid  is not a valid value for INt32" . My application is 64 bit so why this happens? and how do I make the int32 to be 64 ?

```
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file_name1);
            string myLine;
            while ((myLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(myLine+"\n");
                count_lines++;

            }
            sr.Close();
            textBox2.Text = count_lines.ToString(); ;
```

Comment: Have you tried `richTextBox.LoadFile`  & `richTextBox.Lines.Length` ?

Comment: The component simply isn't designed to take that much text. What's the point in loading a 100+MB file into a text box? The scrollbar will be unusable in any realistic sense, and navigation around a document that size will be near impossible. If you really need to do this, you'll need to come up with your own solution that pages in sections of the file and overrides scrollbar behaviour etc.

Comment: That's several dozen copies of Tolstoy's War and Peace.  War is what your user will think of.

Comment: can I simply increase the MaxLength? richTextBox1.MaxLength = 4147483647; I get this msg: Can not convert uint to int

Comment: would it be possible to apply pattern for either richTextBox.LoadFile or  File.ReadAllText()? meaning would it be possible to only get lines which has/which contains a certain string? btw, what is richTextBox.Lines.Length for in this context?

Comment: @JohnRyann `btw, what is richTextBox.Lines.Length for in this context?` Since you are trying to count the lines in your question :)

Comment: @JohnRyann Even if you got it to load it would be unusable. Read Hans's and Spender's comments. Just don't do this.

Comment: +1 for the comment by spender. Anyways you cant change the the MaxLength to int64, because it is a property of the RichTextBox-control - unless you create your own RichTextBox-control from scratch...

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837086/c-sharp-loading-a-large-file-into-a-wpf-richtextbox

Answer (score 0):

(I'll respond to your comment as an answer, to enhance the readability)

**Q:** (by John Ryann )

> would it be possible to apply pattern for either richTextBox.LoadFile
>   or File.ReadAllText()? meaning would it be possible to only get lines
>   which has/which contains a certain string?

**A:**

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("@c:\MyBigFile.log");

string line = sr.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    if(line.Contains("Error"))
    {
        richTextBox.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
sr.Close();
```

Comment: thanks.actually my question from the comment was applying pattern for richTextBox.LoadFile and/or ReadAllText. by definition , it cant. because those methods will read file all at once.