# SQL Server datecolumn NOT greater than another date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this statement in T-SQL

```
[dateReturned] [DATE] NULL 
   CONSTRAINT [Date_Returned] CHECK (dateReturned >= dateRented),
```

but when I execute the whole query I am getting this error.

> Msg 8141, Level 16, State 0, Line 17
>   Column CHECK constraint for column 'dateReturned' references another column, table 'Rental'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 17
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

What is wrong with the statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-column CHECK constraints must be defined at the table level. Constraints defined at the column level can't reference other columns

From the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837086/c-sharp-loading-a-large-file-into-a-wpf-richtextbox) :

> You can apply multiple CHECK constraints to a single column.
>
> You can also apply a single CHECK constraint to multiple columns by creating it at the table level.

Taken from [another MSDN page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Vendors ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Vendor_CreditRating
CHECK (CreditRating >= 1 AND CreditRating <= 5)
```

Comment: Thanks I think it worked. But I have another issue so opened a new question