# From Date < To Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
declare @Education table (
ID                             int,
[From]                         date,
[To]                           date,
TitleOfQualification           nvarchar(100),
OrganisationProvidingEducation nvarchar(100),
City_ID                        int,
Country_ID                     int,
actionType                     nvarchar(20));
```

This is a table im using and i want to make that 'From date' always be before the 'To date' ..for ex:  when i enter a value to ' From date' it should be always little than 'To Date' (From date < To date) . Can somebody help me please?

Comment: what you want ?? and what you have tried for that ??

Comment: You need a check constraint. CHECK around (pun intended)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175672/sql-server-datecolumn-not-greater-than-another-date-column

Comment: select T.Item.query ('./ID') .value ('.', 'int') , T.Item.query ('./FromDate') .value ('.', 'date') , T.Item.query ('./ToDate') .value ('.', 'date') , T.Item.query ('./__action') .value ('.', 'nvarchar(20)') from @xmlInput.nodes ('/SQLP/P/data/dataelement/EDU/HREducation') as T(Item) add constraint CHECK_DATE CHECK (FromDate < ToDate and FromDate<=GETDATE() and ToDate <= GETDATE()); ...........Why this doesnt work on me ?

Comment: @Danja why would you think that would work? You can't just slap some ddl into the middle of a query. You need to read about constraints and understand what they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `check` constraint:

```
declare @Education table (
    ID                             int,
    FromDate                       date,
    ToDate                         date,
    TitleOfQualification           nvarchar(100),
    OrganisationProvidingEducation nvarchar(100),
    City_ID                        int,
    Country_ID                     int,
    actionType                     nvarchar(20),
    check (FromDate < ToDate)
);
```

Don't use `from` and `to` as column names.  These are reserved words and an integral part of the SQL syntax.

Comment: Come on man, this was always going to be a dupe.

Comment: select T.Item.query ('./ID') .value ('.', 'int')
                  , T.Item.query ('./FromDate') .value ('.', 'date')
                  , T.Item.query ('./ToDate') .value ('.', 'date')
                  , T.Item.query ('./__action') .value ('.', 'nvarchar(20)')
             from @xmlInput.nodes ('/SQLP/P/data/dataelement/EDU/HREducation') as T(Item)
     add constraint CHECK_DATE CHECK (FromDate < ToDate and FromDate<=GETDATE() and ToDate <= GETDATE());

Why this doesnt work on me ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add a constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE education 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_DATES CHECK ([from] < [to]);
```

Comment: select T.Item.query ('./ID') .value ('.', 'int') , T.Item.query ('./FromDate') .value ('.', 'date') , T.Item.query ('./ToDate') .value ('.', 'date') , T.Item.query ('./__action') .value ('.', 'nvarchar(20)') from @xmlInput.nodes ('/SQLP/P/data/dataelement/EDU/HREducation') as T(Item) add constraint CHECK_DATE CHECK (FromDate < ToDate and FromDate<=GETDATE() and ToDate <= GETDATE()); 
.
.
.
Why this doesnt work on me ?