# How can I use a BackgroundWorker to read in new lines from a log file?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm creating a cutom log file viewer at the moment, it can handle small files fine but some log files are at least 100MB+ and it struggles a lot to handle them.

I've looked around and what I've got from it is that I can use a BackgroundWorker to do it.

I've tried this so far:

```
//calling the background thread to start
BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorker_DoWork);
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);

bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(logfile.FileName);
```

Then in the bgWorker_DoWork method:

```
void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText((string)e.Argument))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //do your stuff here
            e.Result += s + '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the completed method:

```
void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["rtb"];
        rtb.Text = (string)e.Result;
    }
}
```

Using this stops the GUI from freezing but it still means you have to wait for the BackgroundWorker thread to finish before any of the file is displayed.

I'd like to know if there is a way in which I can use the background thread to load the file while only the lines in view inside the RichTextBox get displayed?

Comment: Don't use BGW. Use tasks and the `async/await` syntax to write almost exactly the same code you would for the concurrent version, eg `while(s=(await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null;await Task.Run(stuff);...; UpdatetheUIAfterTheLoop();`

Comment: As for partially loading a large file in a RTF box, that's a *different* question. In this case you wouldn't need to load the lines one by one, a single `var text=await sr.ReadToEndAsync();` is enough.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so if I were to use the `var text = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();` it would fill the RTF as it goes?

Comment: No, it would load the text in the background. The "magic" is that after the `await` call you are back in the UI thread and you can set the RTF's text directly. Loading the text won't block your UI. If the RTF takes too long to render though, you *can't* fix it with tasks or threads - it's a UI operation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay I see that's useful, would I just set the RTF's text from the `text` variable?

Comment: Isn't that what your last line does? `rtb.Text = somestring` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah it is, well it just takes the complete string that the BGW returns when it finishes

Comment: @Casey Williams, don't concatenate strings with += operator, because they are immutable and it's much much longer than using [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan Cool, will do - thanks!

Comment: @Casey Williams, if you want to show really big log file, try to use [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in pair with [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You don't need to show the whole file, just some part.

Comment: Could find some direction from the answers given in [C# - Loading a large file into a WPF RichTextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837086/c-sharp-loading-a-large-file-into-a-wpf-richtextbox)

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable
This is horribly inefficient

```
e.Result += s + '\n';
```

Use

```
e.Result = Sr.ReadToEnd();
```

If you want to display as you go you could do like 1000 at a time using ReportsProgress but use StringBuilder not +=

Comment: Thank you, will do. A lot better peformance just from using sb!

Answer (score -1):

You can use thread

```
new Thread(() => 
{
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText((string)e.Argument))
{
    string s = String.Empty;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //do your stuff here
        e.Result += s + '\n';
    }

    SomeTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => SomeTextBox.Text = s;));
 }


}).Start();
```

Comment: Why? This is actually trickier than a BGW to get right - what happens with exceptions? Besides, by using the `async/await` syntax you don't need to manually work with threads.

Comment: Background worker is not meant to be used with new code, it is an effectively deprecated method that has been replaced by Tasks that take all of its functionality, build on it and make it much easier to use, as well as allow you to do things that BGW cannot. Read this for a better understanding and more info. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html