# Load Textfile into wpf RichTextBox using DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, richtextbox

i am new to wpf and databinding and i am trying to implement a text editor inside my program. i am using RichTextBox component for it and i need to be able to show and edit big text files about 300 mb or may be more in the compomnent with a good performance and without having OutOfMemoryException.i believe there is something completely wrong in how i use the compoment because it's extremely slow and uses a huge amount of memory even for a 15 mb strings. Can i some how bind the RichTextBox with a Reader and be able to load the data as i scroll up and down without loading the whole file to the memory.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Loading a large file into a WPF RichTextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837086/c-sharp-loading-a-large-file-into-a-wpf-richtextbox)

Comment: if you're new to wpf i suggest avoiding RichTextBox  like the plague, it is the least MVVM control in the WPF framework, so the only lessons it will teach you are bad ones

Answer (score 0):

The RichTextBox is not designed to edit large text files.  It wants to have the entire text in memory.  Unfortunately all the commercial text edit controls have the same limitation.  One idea is to to take a look at visual studio code which is open source and handles large files very well.